# showing different dynamic div tags depend on the radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have these radio buttons:

```
<input name="selector" value="1" type="radio" id="1" />
<input name="selector" value="2" type="radio" id="2" />
```

Then, I want to show the proper dynamic `<div>` depending on the selected radio button.

Here's the `<div>` tag:

```
<div id="product_{selector#ID}">                                                                                            
...
</div>
```

So as you can see the ID of this `<div>` should be dynamic. Could it be handled with javascript?

Comment: What exactly is dynamic about the div? Are you generating additional content or is the content already on the page?

Comment: Do you want show different div depends of the selected radio? You can change the visibility CSS attribute or do you want to create using DOM?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast the ID of the div is dynamic and the content has no important in this case.

Comment: @caballerog because of the some circumstances I can't create two div and it should be only one!

Comment: @Snowleaf I just answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the `div`'s `id` is dynamic, apply the same principle for `:radio` too:

```
<input name="selector" value="1" type="radio" id="r_{selector#ID}" />
<input name="selector" value="2" type="radio" id="r_{selector#ID}" />
```

And for the jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $("input:radio[name='selector']").click(function () {
    $("#" + this.id.replace("r", "product")).show();
  });
});
```

You can use this logic to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty way to achieve what you're after

```js
$("input:radio[name='selector']").click(function() {
  var rdId = $(this).val();
  $("div").hide();
  $("#product_" + rdId).show();
});
```

```css
div { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="selector" value="1" type="radio" name="radio" id="1" /> 1
<input name="selector" value="2" type="radio" name="radio" id="2" /> 2

<div id="product_1">                                                                                            
..... 1
</div>

<div id="product_2">                                                                                            
..... 2
</div>
```

The snippet doesn't want to work on stackoverflow, but [here it is in codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrbPWy)

Comment: unfortunately I can't create two div in the html code. It should only be one dynamic tag.

Comment: That was simply for demonstration purposes. You can keep your dynamic tag, as long as it appends a matching value to the radio button, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This solution manipulates the DOM of your page.

Your html would be

```
<body>
 <input name="selector" value="1" type="radio" id="1" />
 <input name="selector" value="2" type="radio" id="2" />

 <div id="main">
   <div id="product_{selector#ID}"></div>
 </div>
```

Your JS

```
function createDiv(id) {
 var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
 myDiv.setAttribute('id', 'product_' + id);
 document.getElementById('main').appendChild(myDiv);
}

function removeDiv() {
 var element = document.getElementById("main");
 while (element.firstChild) {
  element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
 }
}
var radio1 = document.getElementById('1');
var radio2 = document.getElementById('2');
radio1.onclick = function(e) {
 removeDiv();
 createDiv(this.id)
};
radio2.onclick = function(e) {
 removeDiv();
 createDiv(this.id)
};
```

Now you can see in the element inspector like the DOM is modified if you select different options.

Answer (score 0):

I took a bit of a different approach by creating a quick JsFiddle to demonstrate how you would dynamically handle these events using JavaScript. Here are the pieces of my example that matter:

**JavaScript**

```
//Initialize variables;
var elements, current, last;

//Initially creates the event listeners
elements = document.getElementsByClassName('product_selection');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
  elements[i].onclick = selectProduct;

//Sets the correct div to be displayed
function selectProduct() {
  current = String(this.id);

  var el = document.getElementById("product_" + current);
  el.style.display = "block";

  if (last !== undefined)
    document.getElementById("product_" + last).style.display = "none";

  last = String(this.id);
}
```

**onload**

Based on whatever is currently already on the page, we set the event listeners to the radio buttons whenever they are clicked. We then append that element id to a list of ids so that we can go back to it later.

**selectProduct()**

Set the clicked radio button to the current item, then we want to ensure that it is displayed. After we are complete, assuming this is not the very first radio button clicked, we will hide the previously shown div and update the last item to be whatever radio button was currently clicked.

The rest of my example just allows for you to view what would happen when a dynamically created radio button/div are made and how the program would handle that DOM manipulation.

http://jsfiddle.net/ejk4z03k/5/